# jQuery - Safari click compatibility query

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a jQuery function that doesn't work in Safari and one that does which I have essentially just lifted from a Stack Overflow question.

I'm just curious, why does this one not work and the other doesn't?

```
$(function(){
$("div.polycontainer").children().on("click", function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    var time = [500, 600, 700];
    var element = ["div.servicesHeader", "div.developmentHeader", "div.aboutHeader"];
    var show = $(element[index]).offset().top;
    $('html').animate({scrollTop: (show) - 115}, (time[index]));
    });
    });
```

This works:

```
$("#fromTHIS").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#toTHIS").offset().top }, 500);
    return true;
});
```

I tried using .click instead of .on ("click") in the first example, only different is I haven't made an array etc in the second - just wanted to test it's functionality first off.

Why is this?

Comment: `on("click", function...` and `.click( function...` are basically the same thing

Comment: Your second code is different from the first since you do not have `$("html, body")`

Comment: Okay but the first code work in Firefox but not Safari and the second code works in both.

Comment: Did you change the code in the first to have `$("html, body")`??????

Comment: Well, html didn't worked but putting body in did. How odd, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
$('html').animate({scrollTop: (show) - 115}, (time[index]));
```

needs to be

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop: (show) - 115}, (time[index]));
```

like the example that works.

Comment: How do I cite this as answered?